# How to play audio files from php through html5 audio element

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

I want to stream an .wav audio file located in the application server directory, the file name should not be exposed to the end user. Im using Yii2 framework by the way, in general, how can I achieve this through PHP?

Comment: I think you can try a server rewrite module.

Answer (score 2):

simple way. If you don't want to expose the file name then don't use name attribute.

```
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

**`src`** is the path of your audio file and **`type`** is the type of the audio.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have managed to find a way to solve the problem.

Controller code

```
    $audioFilePath = "audio_file_absolute_path.wav"

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Type: audio/wav'); // sets the output content type to wav
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($audioFilePath)); // sets the legth of the file (in order to the HTML5 player to access the audio duration)
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test_audio.wav"'); // set an output file name

    readfile($audioFilePath); // reads the file
```

View code (The audio player)

```
          <audio controls>
               <source id="audioPlayerSource" src="<? 'Url of audio file read controller function' ?>" type="audio/wav">
          </audio>
```

This way the audio file in the server gets streamed to the audio player in the view

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach($video as $video) { ?>
       <video width="100%" height="390" controls="">
           <source src="<?php echo $video['video'];?>" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
<?php } ?>
```